# Android load and modify file

Tags: android, file-io

I have a short question about writing to a file in android. I am writing a game where I use a xml file to save some data about the level stats. Now I have seen that if I save this xml file in AssetManager it is not possible to change it (only permissions to read files).

Now because I can only modify files which are in the filesystem of android (using openFileInput and openFileOutput to work with it) I wonder where I have to save my (already existing) xml file in my eclipse project so that I can use openFileInput to load it and change it via code.

Do I have to make a new folder? E.g. project_path/files/myxml.xml.
Is it even possible to load a file which was created (outside the AssetManager folder) before installing the .apk to target?
If it is possible does anybody have some example code?

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such place. Installation of android apps does not include an automatic step that would copy your content from apk to the internal folder (and your application does not reside in the folder either).

You will have to create your XML file in code, possibly checking for its existence before each access (or using some other marker).

Comment: thanks for the fast and clear answer! saved me a lot of time searching